# combining two 1d arrays into a 2d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, formatting

I am trying to possibly get this program to print out as.

```
Smith     1000
doe       1200
john      1400
bailey    900
potter    1600
```

the program itself has to arrays I either need to find out a way of possibly combining the two 1d arrays or just a way to format it correctly  so it prints out in the above way.

The Program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TwoArrays {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[]args){
        String [] name = new String[5];
        int [] vote = new int[5];

        String lastname;
        int votecount;
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<name.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter the last name of the candidate: ");
            lastname = console.next();
            name[i]= lastname;
            System.out.println("Enter the number of votes the candidate got: ");
            votecount = console.nextInt();
            vote[i] = votecount;
        }

        String printing = Print(name);
        int printing2 = Print2(vote);

    }

    public static String Print(String [] pname){

        for (int i=0; i<pname.length; i++){
                System.out.println(pname[i]+ "      \n");
        }
        return "nothing";

    }
    public static int Print2(int [] pvote){
        for (int i=0; i<pvote.length; i++){
                System.out.println(pvote[i]+ "      \n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a hash map where the name is the key, and the votes are the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need set reasonable spaces using `System.out.printf`. Here I put `%-15s` for left alignment. You can easily calculate it form `pname` sizes.

```
 public static void print(String[] pname, int[] pvote) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pname.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-15s   %d\n", pname[i], pvote[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"just a way to format it correctly so it prints out in the above way.":

```
 public static void Print(String [] pname, int [] votes){

        for (int i=0; i<pname.length; i++){
                System.out.printf("%-10s %5d\n", pname[i], votes[i]);
        }
    }
```

Then obvious call it just once, with both arrays as arguments:

```
Print(name, vote);
```

(with latest edit, you get some nice alignment. The name is left aligned in a field of 10, the number is right aligned in a field of width 5. You can add other characters in between (for example, a `:`) just by inserting it into the format string.)

Comment: I tried this it did not work correctly first off if it is a void the return can't be there and when I went to call 'Print(name, vote)' nothing ended up printing

Comment: Sorry - your comment was truncated. What is the error you are getting? I thought that `return` with nothing is valid as the end of a `void` function... And this looks remarkably similar to @Masud's code - is that not working for you either?

Comment: it was just the return that was throwing things off.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<pname.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(pname[i]+ "      "+pvote[i]);
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use a tab so the numbers align as requested in the example. Or print the name in a fixed-width field.

Comment: Yes, that would be tidier. I only used fixed width because that was what was in the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as an instance variable:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> candidateMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then in your loop:

```
System.out.println("Enter the last name of the candidate: ");
lastname = console.next();      
System.out.println("Enter the number of votes the candidate got: ");
votecount = console.nextInt();
candidateMap = candidateMap.put(lastname, votecount);
```

Then your print method (credit to @Masud for proper print formatting):

```
public static void Print(){
    for (String candidate : candidateMap.keySet()){
            System.out.printf("%-15s   %d\n", candidate, candidateMap.get(candidate));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tab `\t` can't display properly for various word length.

Comment: @Masud you're right. hope you don't mind if I use what you have in your answer with proper credit.